Is a class considered thread safe if it throws an exception on concurrent access?
Ideally we expect to be able to safely call methods on a thread safe class from multiple threads expecting an output as if the methods had been serialized in some order. If I have a class that throws an exception on concurrent access (and does not leave the class in an inconsistent state), can this class be called thread safe?

Isn't this just a semantics question? I guess I'd call it thread-safe since it obeys it's contract whether or not it's called concurrently.

Seems like a half-baked solution. If it were my class, the exception that I'd have it throw would be an assertion error. If your API has rules (e.g., a rule that says no two threads may concurrently use the same instance of the class), and if some program breaks a rule, then that program is defective. The sooner you can detect defective usage and tell the developer about it, the less likely they will be to release their defective program to their customers. In many languages, an assert statement is the right way to do it.
